# How to cancel Picasso fetch requests by tag?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-imageview, picasso

When I enter an activity I'm calling this method:

```
    private void cacheImagesAndLoadToMemory() {
        for (City city : cities) {
            Picasso.with(this).load(city.getImageUrl()).tag("fetch_images").fetch();
        }
    }
```

This fetches around 200 images which equates to around 45MB of data. Then I attach a fragment to this activity but when I leave the fragment I want the requests for the 200 images to be cancelled. So I have this code set up.

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).cancelTag("fetch_images");
    }
```

But the fetch requests are not being cancelled. I have a bandwidth monitor on my status bar and can see that data keeps being pulled until all 200 images have been cached. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I've never used Picasso, but looking at the docs `tag` is an `Object` - so I'd suggest you pass the same `String` Object, or indeed any common Object, when setting the `tag()` and when using `cancelTag()` - currently there is no guarantee of object equality if Picasso uses `==` operator when comparing tags.

Comment: Yeah I've tried it with static Strings and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a well known bug, cf. [Github bug #1205](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1205).
Unfortunately Picasso project does not seem to move forward lately.